# Maven gae plugin and hot redeploy

Tags: eclipse, maven, maven-gae-plugin

Im working with maven-gae-plugin-0.9.4.jar.

I have a problem with hot redeploy while developping, in the local server.

I run **mvn gae:run** to start the server. I'll try to configure the plugin with a scanIntervalSeconds, as i can do in the mave-jetty-plugin, but that does'nt work. I tryed to search for a solution for days but had not luck.

I can do a workaround, executing **resources:resources compiler:compile war:exploded** in a separated console or from eclipse, but it's really sad the plugin can't do that alone.

Any suggestions?